# What is the recommended way to use fully homomorphic encryption which supports numpy matrix operations?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, matrix-multiplication

For a project I'm working on, I need to perform addition, subtraction and dot operations on relatively large encrypted 2x2 dimensional matrices.

The project is written in python and I am using the numpy library for matrix operations.
In order to be able to encrypt the data and perform mathematical operations, I received a strong recommendation to use fully homomorphic encryption, however, I cannot find an FHE library that supports numpy dot operations on 2x2 matrices. So far I have tried looking at MS SEAL, pyFHEL and Zama/Concrete-numpy. Each have their flaws and do not fully support my requirements.

What would be your recommendation to achieve my goal? Efficiency is an important factor and I'm willing to consider other programming languages or alternatives if they support all my requirements.

Comment: What is numpy dot operation? Entrywise multiplication? Or just a normal matrix multiplication?

Comment: Also, how are the matrices large if they are 2x2?

Comment: The dot us a regular matrix multiplication. By saying that the matrices are large, I mean that they can contain a large amount of elements (hundreds of them)